# ServiceStack AutoQuery - Anomaly When Using "?Fields="

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have noticed an anomaly when using "?Fields=" in version 4.0.55 (pre-release on MyGet).

We have an Employee table with three 1:1 relationships - EmployeeType, Department and Title:

```
public partial class Employee {
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(EmployeeType))]
    public int EmployeeTypeID { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Department))]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Title))]
    public int TitleID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class EmployeeType {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Department {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<Title> Titles { get; set; }
}

public class Title {
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Department))]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The latest update to 4.0.55 allows related DTOs to be requested using `?Fields=` on the query string like this:

```
/employees?fields=id,firstname,lastname,departmentid,department
```

Note that the "proper" way to request a related DTO (department) is to also request the foreign key field (departmentid, in this case).

We wondered if there was a way to return all of the Employee table fields and only selected related DTOs, so in testing we found that this request works:

```
/employees?fields=department
```

We get back all the Employee table fields plus the related Department DTO - **with one strange thing** - the Employee's ID field is populated with the Employee's **TitleID** values.

Specifying the foreign key field in the request fixes that anomaly:

```
/employees?fields=id,departmentid,department
```

but we lose all of the other Employee fields.

Is there a way that to get all of the Employee fields and selected related DTOs?

Here is our AutoQuery DTO:

```
[Route("/employees", "GET")]
public class FindEmployeesRequest : QueryDb<Employee>,
    IJoin<Employee, EmployeeType>,
    IJoin<Employee, Department>,
    IJoin<Employee, Title> {

    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int[] IDs { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string[] UserIDs { get; set; }
    public int? EmployeeTypeID { get; set; }
    public int[] EmployeeTypeIDs { get; set; }
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public int[] DepartmentIDs { get; set; }
    public int? TitleID { get; set; }
    public int[] TitleIDs { get; set; }
    public string LastNameStartsWith { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] DateOfBirthBetween { get; set; }
    public DateTime[] HireDateBetween { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(MONTH({Field}) = {Value})", Field = "DateOfBirth")]
    public int? BirthMonth { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(DAY({Field}) = {Value})", Field = "DateOfBirth")]
    public int? BirthDay { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(FirstName LIKE {Value} OR LastName LIKE {Value} OR PreferredName LIKE {Value})", ValueFormat = "%{0}%", Field = "ID")]
    public string NameSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "(FirstName LIKE {Value} OR LastName LIKE {Value} OR PreferredName LIKE {Value} OR Department.Name LIKE {Value} OR Title.Name LIKE {Value})", ValueFormat = "%{0}%", Field = "ID")]
    public string BasicSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "EmployeeTypeName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string EmployeeTypeSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "DepartmentName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string DepartmentSearch { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Template = "({Field} LIKE {Value})", Field = "TitleName", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
    public string TitleSearch { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does your AutoQuery DTO look-like? Note: Wildcard's wont be supported, fields need to match 1:1 with fields in the joined SqlExpression which are used to construct the underlying SELECT that's sent to the RDBMS to return the populated resultset.

Comment: I updated the question with our AutoQuery DTO.  Thanks.

Comment: That's quite an impressive AutoQuery DTO :) FYI I've added a wildcard short-hand where you can specify all fields in a table with `employee.*` which should help in selecting fields you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

Support for wildcard custom field lists was added [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/c223df4ec7bd987820363aa6d3fd1952902ee33d) where you can specify all fields of the primary or joined table by adding a `.*` suffix, e.g:

```
?fields=id,departmentid,department,employee.*
```

It essentially serves as a substitute placeholder which will be replace it with all fields in the specified table.

This change is available from v4.0.55 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).